# The fastest way to push changes from vendor directory to composer package

Tags: php, git, github, laravel-5, composer-php

I have a `Laravel` project and I'm using a `composer`. I have a library in it and I've found a small bug there. It's my custom library under the `git`.

What is the fastest way to push that changes?

The only way I see from now is to:

- `git clone` my library to some temporary folder
- Remember and copy-paste all the changes(cause I was fixing but in the `/vendor` dir)
- Run `composer update`

Could be there any other, faster way? I'd like make changes right in the vendor dir and somehow push that changes.

**P.S.**
As an answer I want to receive

> No, it's impossible to do faster because of *x*, *y*, *z*.

or

> Yes, you can. For that you have to do *x*, *y*, *z*.

Comment: and what's the problem with this process? how do you see that it is that slow?

Comment: @hassan cause for that package I have to have some sort of *stand*. For example, it's Laravel-depended package and I have to install Laravel first, write code, etc.
I receive money for my time and can't do that manipulations each time I have to do a minor fix or fix a typo in the comment. Making fixes right in the `vendor` and syncing them with a few commands would allow me to improve the development speed, cause sometimes I'm too lazy to do all that manipulations for 1 typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested…

Linux or macOS: Yes, you can. For that you have to do something like

1. Store your new code somewhere else as backup:

   ```
   mv …/vendor/mylib/ …/vendor/mylib_backup/
   ```
2. Optional: Delete your temp repo:

   ```
   rm -r ~/git/mylib/
   ```
3. Clone your repo:

   ```
   git clone repo-url ~/git/mylib
   ```
4. Create a symlink so that if you go into …/vendor/mylib you are really in ~/git/mylib:

   ```
   ln -s ~/git/mylib …/vendor/mylib
   ```
5. Run

   ```
   composer update
   ```
6. Run

   ```
   git status
   ```

Maybe you get some artefacts. You can ignore them in a .gitignore file.

Which system do you use? To create a symlink on Windows you can try mklink IIRC.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I use macOS.